# Find length of row using VBA

Tags: vba

Is there a way to find the length of a row in VBA (counting only cells that are not empty)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: obviously he wants to count the cells in an Excel sheet row that are not empty

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am looking for a way to count the number of cells in a row that are not empty. Thank you all again.

Comment: Something like `=COUNTA(1:1)` will return the number of nonblank cells in row 1. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If your thought of "length" matches the last non-empty cell:
[Last non-empty cell in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column)

```
=INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))
```

Excel 2007+