# VBA taking too long to apply the formula to the given range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

Please refer attached Image below.  VBA code is taking more than 30 minutes to update the formula in Column F till the last row based on latest quarter information.

[image]

For Example, if I have **Q1 data** and **Q2 data** then formula should calculate based on Q2 data as it is the **latest quarter**.  **This a main requirement**.

I have done the below things.

1) Created a Named rages for each quarter/Column 
`Q1 =OFFSET(Data!$B$2;0;0;COUNTA(Data!$A:$A)-1;1)`; 
`Q2 =OFFSET(Data!$C$2;0;0;COUNTA(Data!$A:$A)-1;1)`; 
`Q3 =OFFSET(Data!$D$2;0;0;COUNTA(Data!$A:$A)-1;1)`; 
`Q4 =OFFSET(Data!$E$2;0;0;COUNTA(Data!$A:$A)-1;1)`;

2) Now in **Column F** I have included the following **IF** condition through VBA code`=IF(Q4_Range>0;E2;IF(Q3_Range>0;D2;IF(Q2_Range>0;C2;IF(Q1_Range>0;B2;""))))`

This is how it looks in the VBA editor 
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =_ "=IF(Q4_Range>0,RC[-1],IF(Q3_Range>0,RC[-2],IF(Q2_Range>0,RC[-3],IF(Q1_Range>0,RC[-4],""""))))"`

When I run the VBA code it **is taking more than 30 minutes to copy this formula till the last row** which is dynamic and will be around 50,000 to 80,000 rows.

### My Complete Code

```
Sub Add_Formula()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

    Set StartCell = Range("A2")

    LastRow = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

      Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Select
      Range("F2:F" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(FF3_RANGE>0,RC[-1],IF(FF2_RANGE>0,RC[-2],IF(FF1_RANGE>0,RC[-3],IF(FF0_RANGE>0,RC[-4],))))"

      Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

End Sub
```

***Is there a way to speed-up process by changing the VBA code?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things that can help:

1. If all you need in Column F is the value of the latest quarter (cells Bx:Ex), then you can simplify your formula without using dynamic named ranges. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507233/4717755) shows several options for you, but since you're almost certainly looking at numbers, the formula in column F should be `=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,$B2:$E2)`.
2. You've got the right approach to apply the formula using VBA (which would be `=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,RC2:RC5)`), but you should always [avoid using `Select` or `Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/4717755).
3. The real key in speeding up your process is to [disable screen updates and automatic calculation](http://www.eident.co.uk/2016/03/top-ten-tips-to-speed-up-your-vba-code/).

Wrapped all together as an example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Formula()
    ToggleAppUpdates False
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Sht
        Dim startCell As Range
        Set startCell = .Range("A2")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,RC2:RC5)"
            .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        End With
    End With
    ToggleAppUpdates True
End Sub

Sub ToggleAppUpdates(ByVal state As Boolean)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = state
        .Calculation = IIf(state, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It is now taking less than 2 seconds to calculate.