# How to count cells in range, with multiple criteria OR how to filter range for countif/counta/subtotal etc

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to count the number of non-empty cells in a range (H5 to J13), where another cell (in column G) also matches a text string from a different cell. I am using a spreadsheet on Google Docs so unfortunately COUNTIFS is not available.

All of these formulas work fine to count non-empty cells in the range:

- =COUNTIF(H5:J13, "<>"&"")
- =SUBTOTAL(3, H5:J13)
- =COUNTA(H5:J13)

However, it seems none of those allow me to filter the range H5:J13 before it counts the cells. Can anyone help with this, or propose a different solution?

The practical application is like this...

THE DATA

Column G shows the staff member rostered, columns H through J show if someone else taught that class instead, on particular dates.

```
COLUMN G --- COLUMN H  --- COLUMN I --- COLUMN J
________________________________________________
ROSTERED --- CLASS 1  ---- CLASS 2 ---- CLASS 3
________________________________________________
Sally ------ [blank] ----- Sue --------- [blank]
Bob -------- Sally ------- Sue --------- [blank]
Sue -------- [blank] ----- [blank] ----- [blank]
```

WHAT I WANT TO CALCULATE

I want to count the number of times that each staff member (Column G) has someone else teach their class (evident by non-empty cells in H through J of that row). For example:

```
COLUMN P --- COLUMN Q  
_____________________
STAFF ------ MISSED  
_____________________
Sally --------- 1 ---
Bob ----------- 2 ---
Sue ----------- 0 ---
```

I thought I could put FILTER(H5:J13, G:G=P4) as the range in the COUNTA or COUNTIF formulas, but I get errors doing this. As mentioned, I cannot used COUNTIFS (which sounds like it would be perfect) as it's not yet supported by Google Docs.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is this worked (worked in Excel): =SUM(IF(ISBLANK(H5),0,1),IF(ISBLANK(I5),0,1),IF(ISBLANK(J5),0,1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if Google Docs accepts array formulas but if it does this formula should work, enter by pressing ctrl+shift+enter. (in excel)

```
=sum(if(H5:J13<>"",if(G5:G13=P4,1,0),0))
```

Comment: @ gtwebb - good answer! In googledocs you can wrap in arrayformula function, i.e. `=arrayformula(sum(if(H5:J13<>"",if(G5:G13=P4,1))))`

Comment: @gtwebb : Check also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20086410/2707864), it may be helpful.

Comment: @sancho.s the link appears to be to the last answer which would find the last cell in column A with something in it.  I don't think that is applicable to this problem.

Comment: @gtwebb - I was referring to the use of a non-array formula.