# excel function that will show date in last column entry

Tags: excel

I have an excel here with multiple columns and row.. lets assume that 11-11 is A1 and 11-12 is A2 and so on.. i want to have an equation if there's any that will display the date of the last entry in a column

```
    A             B        C        D
```

11-11-2013            ***_*__*_*__*_*__***1****_*__*_*_***2****_*__*_*__*_*____**        1

11-12-2013            ***_*__*_*____***2****_*__*_*__***4****_*__*_*__*_*__*_***_3

11-13-2013            ***_*__*_*___***3****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_5

11-14-2013_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**_6

11-15-2013

i want to put in the last row in each column the equation that will show the last date like in column B it will display 11-13 in column C 11-12 and D 11-14...

ps: sorry for the editing dont know how to show spaces.. =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Last non-empty cell in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX(A:A,INDEX(MAX(($A:$A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))),0))`

OR

`=INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))` and hit CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER

I found this answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column). Next time try searching around a bit more before you post a question.

**EDIT**
This function gets the date of the last entry to B

`=INDEX(A:A,INDEX(MAX(($B:$B<>"")*ROW(B:B)),0))`

This function gets the date of the last entry to B

`=INDEX(A:A,INDEX(MAX(($C:$C<>"")*ROW(C:C)),0))`

Change values as needed

**Tested in Google Docs**

Comment: yup ive tried that one and tried the rest of the answers from all the previous post but i cant seem to make it work... hmmm forgot to mention that im doing this on google doc so is there a difference?