# For Excel 2010: How to get last value of custom sorted column with a Filter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am able to get a column into version sorted order. The issue is Excel formula do not seem to handle tables that have an Excel Filter on them to excluded unwanted rows. VBA macros are not an option due to security limitations. I have seen, and used the answers from [Last non-empty cell in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column).

Here is a simple example that reproduces the issue. Start with conventional sorted column A:

```
A_1.0.0_a
A_2.0.19_a
A_2.0.2_a
B_1.0.0_a
```

Remove B_ row with a manually created Excel Filter "does not contain" B_ . Now:

```
A_1.0.0_a
A_2.0.19_a
A_2.0.2_a
```

Put in correct sort order using Excel 2010 manual operations: copy/paste column A, Convert Text to Columns twice, and Sort using custom 3 level sort:

```
A_1.0.0_a
A_2.0.2_a
A_2.0.19_a
```

The catch seems to be the Excel Filter is not used in Excel formula. For instance used all 8 Excel formula from the question "Last non-empty cell in a column". The results using Excel formula at best return the Filtered out B_1.0.0_a

```
B_1.0.0_a    ={INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))}
B_1.0.0_a    Excel autoedited is now: 
               ={IF(ISBLANK(A1048576),INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))),A1048576)}
B_1.0.0_a    Excel autoedited is now: =INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))
B_1.0.0_a    =INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))
B_1.0.0_a    With COUNTA is: =OFFSET($A$1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0)
B_1.0.0_a    =INDEX(A:A,INDEX(MAX(($A:$A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))),0))
4            =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A:$A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))
0            =F7-INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A))
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: consider about using `SUBTOTAL` function (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx) instead `MAX`, `COUNT` and etc. It doesn't take into account hidden rows

Answer (score 2):

Try this version to get last visible value in A2:A1000 when filtered

`=LOOKUP(2,1/SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A1000)-ROW(A2),0)),A2:A1000)`

Comment: This is correct. Returned: A_2.0.19_a