# Summing numeric portion of cell when alpha portion of cell is the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that has columns for dates and the values can be either "1v, .5v, 1p, .5p, 1s, .5s"
I have 3 columns in each row one for each letter "v, p and s". I want to be able to add the total of all cells in the range grouped by letter and then display the sum for each letter in it's respective column (v, p or c).

Here is an example of the sheet:

```
Name     Vacation   Personal   Sick   1/5/15  1/6/15  1/7/15  1/8/15
Billy       1.5        1         0       .5v    1v              1p
```

It is the formula that goes in the vacation/personal/sick cell that I just can't figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the range you posted starts at A1, use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((RIGHT($E2:$G2,1)="v")*LEFT($E2:$G2,LEN($E2:$G2)-1))
```

in B2. Change `"v"` and the range to use suitably.

Pro:

- **It is not an array formula**. See [why this may be important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20086410/2707864)

Con:

- I could not make it work with blank cells.

Comment: I was having an issue and getting a #VALUE!.  After some lever pulling I realized that it is because some of the values may be blank.  Once I put in values for all the range then it worked.  I've updated the range to add in a H2 and removed the value in H2 to better represent the issues. Is there a way to tell the formula to ignore no/null celled values

Answer (score 2):

I went down the array formula route and came up with essentially the same formula as @Sancho.s :-

```
=SUM(LEFT($E2:$H2,LEN($E2:$H2)-1)*(RIGHT($E2:$H2)="v"))
```

You could modify it to take account of blanks:-

```
=SUM(IF($E2:$H2<>"",LEFT($E2:$H2,LEN($E2:$H2)-1)*(RIGHT($E2:$H2)="v")))
```

Perhaps this would be better, to ignore any mis-formatted cells:-

```
=SUM(IFERROR(LEFT($E2:$H2,LEN($E2:$H2)-1)*(RIGHT($E2:$H2)="v"),0))
```

These all have to be put in with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: I was able to get your 2nd formula working.  I could not get the if statement to work with @sancho.s' SUMProduct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This "array entered" version will also allow blanks

`=SUM(IF(RIGHT(E2:G2)="v",SUBSTITUTE(E2:G2,"v","")+0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Neat - I hadn't thought of doing it that way.