# Cell Text to Number (based on Cell Text Value)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table:

```
2.0 M
1.9 M   
1455.0 K    
1386.9 K
```

Is there a way that I can convert that table into Numerical values based on the Letter at the end of the table such that the following is output:

```
2.0 M   2,000,000
    1.9 M   1,900,000
    1455.0 K    1,455,000
    1386.9 K    1,386,900
```

so: Remove the letter and multiply by either 1,000,000 or 1,000

Thanks,

Comment: Is the letter in the cell (column A) with the number or is the letter in another column cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or this one (doesn't matter how many spaces):-

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),"K","E3"),"M","E6"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I had seen a similar approach by @barry houdini and copied from the master http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784048/summing-numeric-portion-of-cell-when-alpha-portion-of-cell-is-the-same/27784868#27784868

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1)="M",LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))*1000000,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))*1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A,** in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="M",1000000*LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="K",1000*LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),A1))
```

For example:

[image]