# Excel macro: Last non-empty cell in a column

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

This is a followup question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5441885/69537).

The following formula can be used to find the value of the last non-empty cell in a column, in Microsoft Excel:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A)
```

My question is, how can I convert this formula to a Macro function? So that I can use it like this:

```
=GetLastValueInColumn('A')
```

Indeed, I need to convert the letter 'A' to range A:A, but don't know how.

Comment: `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like,

```
Function GetLastValueInColumn(sCOL As String)
    GetLastValueInColumn = Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, sCOL).End(xlUp).Value
End Function
```

The call to *Parent* should resolve to the worksheet that the function is called from. This function's behaviour could be expanded to address another worksheet or the `ActiveSheet` if it was required to be called from within VBA.