# Formula to sum the last thirteen rows in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I was searching for a formula that sums the last thirteen rows in a column from the bottom. I found:

```
=SUM(INDEX(R:R,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,R:R,1)):INDEX(R:R,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,R:R,1)-13,0))
```

and it works for the most part, except if the last thirteen rows are empty [image] it adds the last thirteen numbers beginning with the last value that is filled in. Here is an example:

[image: an example]

as you can see column V gives 7.4 because it counts the last thirteen values -  well past the last thirteen values from the bottom.

How do I make the formula evaluate empty cells as zero so that it gives me `0` in V?

Comment: Are you trying to sum over rows 99 to 111? If so you could use `=SUM(R99:R111)`

Comment: No not just adding rows 99-111 THE formule should constantly add THE last 13 rows in each colomn even if i add more rows

Comment: So you want to sum the last non-blank cell in each column and the 12 cells above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SUM "N" Last Rows of DATA**

This is my understanding of the requirements:

The `DATA` has 2 rows of *Headers* and other 2 of *Totals* at the top, therefore an `Excel Table` does not apply.

Rows `6:7` are holding the `TOTALS TO DATE` and `TOTALS LAST PAGE`. `TOTALS LAST PAGE` is the `SUM` of the last `13` rows of the `DATA`. Therefore, we need to identify the last row of the `DATA` instead of the last non-blank row.

This solution assumes:

The `DATA` is located at range `C3:R38` *(adjust as required)*, with the first 4 rows as Header and Totals; and the data details start at row `7`.

In order to be able to calculate the `DATA Last Row` we need to identify a field that its last row cell is *always populated* (i.e. it will never be empty). To demonstrate this solution I assumed that this field is located in column `C`. It’s also assumed that the fields for which we need to add the totals are in columns `F:R`

This solution works with the following three working cells

1. `DATA Last Row` : This `FormulaArray` is an important part of the formulas to add the `TOTALS LAST PAGE` of several columns *(+20 fields)*, as such having it just once in a working cell, will reduce the resources needed to perform the workbook calculations.

Enter this `FormulaArray` in cell `I2`

*(Formulas Array are entered by pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously)*

```
=MAX( (C:C <> "" ) * ROW(C:C) )
```

2. `Last Page Rows` *(input from user)* : Located at `E2`, this working cell holds the number of rows of the last page (number of rows to be added upwards from last row of the `DATA`). It provides the flexibility to update the results if the number of rows to add changes, instead of changing each one of the formulas *(+20 fields)*, the user just enters the new number of rows in this cell.

Enter `13` in cell `E2`

3. `Last Rows to Add (calc)` - *Optional* : Used to calculate the number of cells to add. To avoid an endless duplication in the case that the `DATA` contains less rows than the expected number of rows of the last page. Although this seems to be an unlikely scenario as per the sample data, still added as it could be useful to other users with similar situation. *This working cell is optional, as such an alternate formula is provided in case it is not implemented.*

Enter this Formula in cell `M2`

```
=IF( $I$2 - $E$2 < ROW( $C$7 ), $I$2 - ROW( $C$7 ), $E$2 )
```

Now to obtain the `TOTALS LAST PAGE` we enter one of these formulas in cell `F6` and copy to the range `G6:R6`

a. `Last Rows to Add (calc)` working cell implemented

```
=SUM( OFFSET( INDEX(F:F, $I$2, 0 ), 0, 0, -$M$2 ))
```

b. `Last Rows to Add (calc)` working cell **no** implemented

```
=SUM( OFFSET( INDEX(F:F, $I$2, 0 ), 0, 0, -$E$2 ))
```

[image: Fig. 1]

*Last 13 rows of data are always added, regardless of their contents*

[image]

*`Last Rows to Add (calc)` no implemented and `DATA` has less than `13` records. `TOTALS LAST PAGE` are inaccurate as the total below is also added*

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for a way to determine the rownumber of last nonblank row in a column ( and count back from there ) in order to determine your `SUM()` range. There's a couple simpler formulas if you're willing to add helper columns and/or format your data into a [table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c). ( Please let me know in comments if so & I can revise the answer).

Without using helper cells & columns though, you could try the following changing the capital `A` to your column of choice `=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&INDEX(ROW(A:A),MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))&":A"&INDEX(ROW(A:A),MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))-13))`

#### Explanation:

1. `INDEX(ROW(A:A),MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))` determines the last nonblank row in column A ( credit to [Doug Glancy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442955/4709762) ). This is an [array formula](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html)  and must be initialized with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> after which the formula should wrap in curly brackets `{=SUM(`...`)}`
2. `INDIRECT()` allows you to declare a dynamic range for the `SUM()` function. The inner argument for `INDIRECT()` function evaluates to `Ax:Ay` where `x` and `y` are the row references of the 13th-to-last and last rows.

If, however, the issue is ***skipping*** non-blank cells in the target column ***at the end of the column***, I can't think of a readable single-cell formula which would allow this. I'd suggest setting a helper cell in which you place a formula to determine the valid cell ranges. Naming this/these cells ( <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to bring up the named range manager ), will allow you to change the syntax to `=SUM(named_range_1,named_range_2,...named_range_13)` with no array formula necessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will run painfully slowly as an Array formula which looks at an entire column really looks at the entire column - not just the cells within the used range. Since OP only has one of these formulas needed, however, that shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon yup, formatting as a table with `ctrl`+`t` would allow for easier evaluation, but the sample given in the OP doesn't appear to have that.

Comment: hi thank you  for your comment the problem that i have with my original formula is that it counts all the values from row 111 back up 13 rows so to row 98 and if you look in cell G6=16.5 witch is correct but in cell V6 its shows 7.4 because it does not recognize that  v111 to v98 the empty cells as a number so it finds the first number in the V cel and than sums everything 13 rows up from that value exmpl: i want it to give me the value from V111 to V98 in this case and that should be 0 but if the first value is in V70 it will sum the values from v70 tov57 and gives me 7.4 hope it makes sense

Comment: @GIO can I suggest trying the "named range" solution in that case. On a new sheet, write a formula that follows criteria such that it will always target the cell you want to start at. Then name the cell with alt+m+m+d as suggested. Sum up from there using the offset method. Apologies but I cannot provide advice on what the formula should be for the named range cell without knowing more about the data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

For the requirement as I interpret it I suggest, in V112:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(V112,-13,0,13,1))
```

Change the reference and rows offset if required in a different cell.

Comment: =SUM(OFFSET(V112,-13,0,13,1))  its what im searching for the only thing thats a problem is that i need the formula to constantly count 13 up from the last row not just 13 up from row 112.

Comment: in my picture its 111 but if i add more lines for example 13 lines  it would be 124 so in you example for column V its v124  so your formula would be  
=SUM(OFFSET(V124,-13,0,13,1)and that is fine if i want to change the value every time  but i need something that automatically chances the "V124" value to the  last value evreytime i add more rows lines

Comment: Okay inserting rows does do that i will see if i can use it that way thank u