# In excel I am trying to track percentage completion of a goal

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I've got the starting weight in one cell. I've got goal weight in another cell. I've got a range of cells where the customer will input their weight every day. I want to have another cell that calculates and displays the percentage completion of their weight loss goal. Basically, I want to take the most recent value added to the weight tracking row and use that to calculate the percentage weight loss goal completion. I could do a percentage completion rate for each day and display them in individual cells under each weight each day, but I just want one cell to take care of that. My problem is getting that most recently added value into my formula. Any pointers on how I would go about that?

Comment: Hi HackinShtuff, welcome to SO.If you could add screenshots it would be easier for us to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a standard formula for finding the last non-empty cell in a row or column [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column). So if you had the weights in (say) row 5, the initial weight in A2, and the target weight in B2 a single-cell formula would look like this:-

```
=($A$2-LOOKUP(2,1/(5:5<>""),5:5))/($A$2-$B$2)*100
```

or you could leave out the *100 and just format it as %.

[image]

Comment: Thanks pal. You're a mensch.