# Obtain last non empty date from column

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I current has an excel table filled with dates that looks something like this, but with more columns and much more rows.

```
2012-01-01   2013-02-04  (empty cell)   2017-01-01   (empty cell)
2011-02-01   2013-02-20   2014-05-05   (empty cell)   2016-03-04
...
```

How can I obtain the latest date from the columns? For example

```
2017-01-01
2016-03-04
...
```

I have tried sorting them using latest to earliest but the sorted data does not return what I wanted. And it sorted my entire table's date instead of sorting them row by row.

I have tried methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column), which suggests me using `=INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))` but I could not make sense of the function nor could I make my table produce the latest date in another cell. Please suggest me any way of obtaining a row of the the latest date using excel formula preferably. (If it is not possible with excel only, please suggest me some alternatives.)

Comment: Will the farthest date to the right always be the "biggest" date.  As in farthest in the future? (or closest to today)?

Comment: @Chrismas007 yes the biggest will always be at the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is sequential like your example, simply use the `Max` formula:

```
=Max(1:1)
=Max(2:2)
```

for each row.

Here is the usage with your sample data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A date is a number and you can get the column index of the last number with,

```
=match(1e99, 1:1)
```

So to get the last date in row 1 then

```
=index(1:1, match(1e99, 1:1))
```

Comment: The full row reference (e.g. `1:1` ) may have to be restricted to something like `A1:Z1` if you plan to put these formulas on the same row in the same worksheet. Using a full row reference will result in a circular reference since the formula contains a range that includes itself.