# subtract the last two non-empty cell in excel

Tags: vba, excel

This is I think a simple problem but I can't seem to find the right solution for it. I don't know if VBA is needed for it. Basically I just want to subtract the last two non-empty cell in Excel. Example: I have the cell A1 and cell B1 and then subtract the value of A1 from B1 and place this value at the same row but another column C1 and so on. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column) to get the last non-empty cell but I need two non-empty cell and perform operation on them.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A)
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Or should I use VBA?

EDIT:

the reason is I'm making a somewhat similar to a balance sheet but a simple one, the user will just enter deposited value at the first column and expenses at the second column and then display the balance in the third column.. and vice versa.

EDIT:
Sample[image]

Comment: If the output cell in not arbitrary then it can be done with a formula.  If the output cell is arbitrary then vba will be needed.

Comment: yes.. the output cell should align based on last non-empty cells of either column... the reason is I'm making a somewhat similar to a balance sheet but a simple one, the user just enter deposited at the first column and expenses at the second column and then display the balance in the third column..

Comment: Could you mock up some data and expected outcome?

Comment: @DirkReichel formula is erroneous

Comment: @ScottCraner updated my question

Comment: oh wow... with the update now, I got the question completely wrong :P

Comment: @DirkReichel Me too! I had to change it several times.

Comment: lol sorry I'm not good in explaining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in C4 and copy down:

```
=SUM($A$3:$A4)-SUM($B$3:$B4)
```

[image]

If you want to copy the formula past the data so it will automatically fill when data is inserted you can do what @Dirk stated:

```
=IF(A4&B4<>"",SUM(A$3:A4)-SUM(B$3:B4),"")
```

Put it in C4 and copy down as far as desired.

This way you can fill the column with the formula and as the data is filled it will change from the empty string to the running total.

Comment: to not get repeats after the last entry: `=IF(A3&B3<>"",SUM(A$3:A3)-SUM(B$3:B3),"")` in C3 and copy down ;)

Comment: thank you but I want the third column not to change if I enter new values below..

Comment: @silent_coder14 Did you try the formula in that situation?  Does it change? It shouldn't

Comment: The numbers below will not effect the numbers above.  The formula only looks at the numbers above the row in which the formula is.  As you can see from the picture, I placed the formula in C4 and copied down.  The numbers in row 5 did not effect the formula in C4 and the numbers in row 6 did not efect the result in C4 and c5

Comment: @silent_coder14 I do not know why you are getting an error.  It works in the above dataset.  Do you have errors in your dataset?  This will cause errors.  It is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @silent_coder14 ahhhhh.  You were using the formula I copied and pasted from Dirk.  sometimes when copying from the comments unseen characters are inserted in the text.  I have fixed it and made the reference to be put in C4 and copied down.  See edit.  You may need to refresh the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Regular formula:

```
=IF(ROW($C1)=1,OFFSET($C1,0,-2)-OFFSET($C1,0,-1),OFFSET($C1,-1,0)+OFFSET($C1,0,-2)-OFFSET($C1,0,-1))
```

Comment: appreciate the help

Answer (score -1):

in cell C3 put "=A3-B3" in cell C4 put "=C3+A4-B4" then copy down.
This will start the balance at 3000 in C3 then add any deposits or minus any withdrawals to the rest of column C.