# Excel Autofill Upwards

Tags: excel, autofill

So I have a file of about 10k lines and I need to autofill upwards every blank value, and then take the next (previous) non-blank value and do the same. It would look like this:

**What I have in my data**
[image]

**What I need**
[image]

Any ideas on how I could do this easily?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last non-empty cell in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

Filter the column F with blank. Enter the below formula in your F2 cell

```
=IF(F3<>"",F3,"")
```

Copy this cell to the rest of the blank cells till the end.

Comment: By any chance, If the content in next cell is empty. It will display it as 0. The empty check is to avoid such behavior.