# How can I delete all but the last two columns in an excel sheet

Tags: vb.net, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that displays the file paths to ~ 13000 files in my vault.  Each row may have a different number of columns.  I am really only interested in the last two columns, the folder its in and the name of the file.  It is far to many rows to do manually.  I need a way to either delete all but the last two columns in every row or sort it by the number of columns.  I am not much of a programmer, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: VBA is the programming language used for Excel macros.  VB.Net is a whole other beast.  Please clarify/correct your intended language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant VBA not VB.NET (Please update your tags if that's the case)

This will put the last two columns (that aren't blank) into column A & B.  So you can either write the code to insert the two columns or do it manually, same with deleting all the columns once the code runs.

```
Public Sub Test()
'Insert 2 columns: A&B

Dim LastCol As Integer
For CurRow = 2 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    LastCol = getLastColumn(CurRow)
    If LastCol > 2 Then
        Sheet1.Cells(CurRow, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(CurRow, LastCol - 1)
        Sheet1.Cells(CurRow, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(CurRow, LastCol)
    End If
Next

'Delete All columns except A&B
End Sub

Private Function getLastColumn(ByVal CurrentRow As Integer) As Integer
getLastColumn = -1

For ColCounter = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1 To 1 Step -1
    If Sheet1.Cells(CurrentRow, ColCounter) <> "" Then
        getLastColumn = ColCounter
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you.  It did 13571 rows in about 10 seconds flat.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more a question concerning how to use excel than vb.net, but I will try to answer it anyways:

Just click on the column headers and drag the mouse to the select all columns you want to delete, then right click on any of the selected columns and select "delete columns" from the appearing context menu.

Comment: Each row may have 6 or maybe 8 column.  Each column represents a folder or sub folder in the file path.  I don't know where the last two columns may be.  Might be column D or maybe column E or something else.  I need a way to find the last two columns and remove everything else.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column

I can't provide a solution because german excel uses translated formula keywords, but you can find the last column index like this:

    =EQUIV("";B1:G1;-1)

and then use INDIRECT to access the last two cells