# Excel - Dynamic Pivot Table that ignores blank rows and subtotal rows

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

So, I have this dynamic pivot table grabbing data from another sheet/tab called Data Import. In Name Manager, this is what I have for the pivot table:
=OFFSET('Data Import'!$A$6,0,0,(COUNTA('Data Import'!$A:$A)),14)

The pivot table work beautifully when I don't have blank rows or rows that have subtotals **throughout the middle of the record** (Data Import tab), but when I do, my dynamic pivot table doesn't show the last 10 or 12 rows of data.

Is there a way of getting around this without adding "+20" at the end of the COUNTA() function in my name manager.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last non-empty cell in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column)

Comment: If it's a **Table**, assign the Name to like `=Table1[ColumnHeader]`

Comment: It's not a table. Not sure if I should make it one though. It's a tab where people will paste +300 rows of data (including unwanted many subtotal rows). Would the table have to be dynamic? How I have it now works well if I add "+20" to the end of the COUNTA() function, but it would not work if I had more than 20 subtotal or blank rows.