# Macro to Count Filter Distinct unique Value

Tags: excel, vba

I Have Table like this, where i have to use macro because my table always change Every day (SSAS)
so i have use macro to filter automatically,

[image]

I am able to sum Amount based on same Vendorname, PONuber and Date on Column E (Subtotal).

[image]

and then filter to show Subtotal AMount >500

I want to show only row >500 (Column E), and pop up message to count PONumber (Column B) how many Unique PO Number (Only Visible Row to count)

[image]

i've been stuck how to count only Visible Unique PO Number and show it on Pop Up message

this is my Macro

```
Sub FilterCOunt_Click()
Dim Condition As Variant
Dim AVal As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Hide, popup  As Long
Dim message  As String

Dim sht As Worksheet
'----------------------------
Dim dictionary As Object
Set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
'---------------------------
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.StatusBar = False
'------------------
Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Columns("E:Z").EntireColumn.Delete
Range("E:Z").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("E1").Value = "Sub Total >500 "

Set sht = ActiveSheet

LastRow = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'-------------------


For i = 2 To LastRow ' with last row count =SUMIFS(I:I,A:A,A8,B:B,B8,C:C,C8)

     AVal = "A" & i

     BVal = "B" & i

     CVal = "C" & i
     Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & i).Formula = "=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A," & AVal & ",B:B," & BVal & ",C:C," & CVal & ")"

Next i

With sht.Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=500"

End With
'----------Count Pop UP
Dim CountPO As Long
Range("G1").FormulaArray =  "=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2),1)),IF(B2:B22<>"",MATCH(""&B2:B22,B2:B22&"",0))),ROW(B2:B22)-  ROW(B2)+1),1))"


MsgBox "We Found " & CountPO & " PO Open(s)", _
vbInformation, "PO Found"
End Sub
```

and this is the formula to count it

```
{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2),1)),IF(B2:B22<>"",MATCH("~"&B2:B22,B2:B22&"",0))),ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2)+1),1))}
```

Comment: I dont Know Why Formula Array Not Working to count Colum B, But If i put it manual in cell Excel  and presss CTRL+SHIFT+ Enter the formula works fine.

Comment: Related: [Escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724)

Comment: Once filtered >500 you can do something like [Create List of Unique Values in Excel
](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=492&v=soVOGldB-Mo&feature=emb_logo)

Answer (score 1):

If you are pulling from a Database via SSAS you can use Power Query to link to your SSAS DataModel to Excel and you can insert a Calculated Measure in Dax from there with DistinctCount.

```
Count:=Calculate(DistinctCount(TableName[PONumber]),TableName[Amount]>500)
```

Alternatively if you want total insights on your specified issue you can add a measured column and then you can use Power Pivot to filter for your criteria live on refresh to the data model, completely negating the need for VBA entirely.

*Incidentally it is pertinent to remember VBA is the sledge hammer of solutions please use the DataModel Tools before you ever think of a macro solution remember, VBA is an Application Programming Language and many IT Security Systems will disable it because it opens the system up for malware, you can literally change any file or program in VBA including calling delete system files*

*Meanwhile having a set DataModel in a locked file that requires user access behind LAN security is easily more secure than allowing your computer to have open programatic access.*

Comment: i dont have power query in my SSAS

Comment: No you use your credentials for access to the Datamodel in Power Query to access your Dataset output from SSAS. Then you can use DAX alternarively you can just get the Tables straight from the Datasource inExcel theough Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative formula (which doesn't require any filtering)

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B20>500,MATCH(A2:A20,A2:A20,0)),ROW(A2:A20)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))
```

It's an array formula so using VBA

```
Range("E1").FormulaArray = "=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B20>500,MATCH(A2:A20,A2:A20,0)),ROW(A2:A20)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))"
```

Comment: I want to count Column B ( PO Number) which visible after filterd and show in Pop up msg

Comment: You'll have to adjust the references to your set up.

Comment: why i Cant use this Formula in Macro? =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(D2,ROW(D2:D22)-ROW(D2),,1)), IF(D2:D22<>"",MATCH("~"&D2:D22,D2:D22&"",0))),ROW(D2:D22)-ROW(D2)+1),1))

Comment: But if i put that formula in Excel without macro it works. and i can count unique value in visible filterd. but not working in macro. Any Suggestion?

Comment: That's a different formula.

Answer (score 0):

A formula for your cell E2, which is not an array formula, is

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2=B$2:B$23)*(A2=A$2:A$23)*(D$2:D$23))
```

Copy it down, as usual.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20086410/2707864) for why not using an array formula (if you have an alternative).

I am not certain this solves your question, as I did not fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. I have implemented `Collection` to get the unique count.

This will count the unique rows in `B column` where `value in E column > 500`.

```
Private Sub GetUniqueCount() AS Variant
Dim Test As New Collection
Dim rng As Range
For i = 2 To 6 'Replace 6 with last row(without filtration)
    Value = Cells(i, "B").Value
    check = Contains(Test, Value)
    If Cells(i, "E").Value > 500 And Not check And Len(Value) > 0 Then
        Test.Add Value, CStr(Value)
    End If
Next i
GetUniqueCount = Test.count
End Sub
'Function to check if the value exists in Collection or not
Public Function Contains(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
Dim obj As Variant
On Error GoTo err
    Contains = True
    obj = col(key)
    Exit Function
err:
    Contains = False
End Function
```

Comment: But i need to show the value from counting row has been filtered to pop up msg box

Comment: You can Store the output `CountPO=GetUniqueCount` and then display it. `MsgBox "We Found " & CountPO & " PO Open(s)", _
vbInformation, "PO Found"`

Comment: How to set GetUniqueCount using My Formula array?

Comment: Above function will replace Formula Array. So, There is no need to use Formula array.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Post my code to a new module.

Step 2: Bind you button to the macro named "filterAndCount"

Step 3: Click the buton and rejoice :-)

Code description:

1) The code loops all the rows in the table.

2) First it checks if the Sub Total is above the limit (500).

3) If equal or below it hides the row and moves on to the next row.

4) If above it checks if the value already exists in the array values above.

5) If it does not exists then the value is added to the array.

6) When all rows have been looped only rows with a Sub Total above the limit is visible.

7) Only the unique and visible PO Numbers have been added to the array.

8) The number of values in the array is dispayed in a message box.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim i As Double
Dim n As Double
Dim subTotalLimit As Double
Dim arr() As String


Sub filterAndCount()

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

i = 2
subTotalLimit = 500
n = 0

ReDim arr(0 To 0) As String
arr(0) = 0

ws.Columns("E:Z").EntireColumn.Delete
ws.Range("E:Z").EntireColumn.Insert
ws.Range("E1").Value = "Sub Total >500 "

Do While ws.Range("B" & i) <> ""

    ws.Range("E" & i).Formula = "=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A" & i & ",B:B,B" & i & ",C:C,C" & i & ")"

    If ws.Range("E" & i) < subTotalLimit Then
        ws.Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        If Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(Range("B" & i).Text, arr(), 0)) Then
            arr(n) = Range("B" & i).Value
            n = UBound(arr) + 1
            ReDim Preserve arr(0 To n) As String
            arr(n) = 0
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox UBound(arr)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  2 [Dictionary Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object), one for totals and one for unique PO's

```vb
Sub filterCOunt()

    Const LIMIT = 500

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, amount As Single
    Dim sVendor As String, sPO As String, msg As String, sKey As String

    Dim dictPO As Object, dictTotal As Object
    Set dictPO = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictTotal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    iLastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' first pass to total by po and vendor
    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow

       sVendor = Trim(ws.Cells(iRow, 1))
       sPO = Trim(ws.Cells(iRow, 2))
       amount = CSng(ws.Cells(iRow, 4))
       sKey = sVendor & "_" & sPO

       ' sub total
       If dictTotal.exists(sKey) Then
          dictTotal(sKey) = dictTotal(sKey) + amount
       Else
          dictTotal.Add sKey, amount
       End If
    Next

    ' second pass for PO numbers
    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow

       sVendor = Trim(ws.Cells(iRow, 1))
       sPO = Trim(ws.Cells(iRow, 2))
       sKey = sVendor & "_" & sPO

       ' sub total
       ws.Cells(iRow, 5) = dictTotal(sKey)
       If dictTotal(sKey) > LIMIT Then
          If Not dictPO.exists(sPO) Then
             dictPO.Add sPO, iRow
          End If
       End If
    Next

    ' filter
    With ws.Range("E1:E" & iLastRow)
       .AutoFilter
       .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & LIMIT
    End With

    msg = "No of open PO's = " & dictPO.Count

    MsgBox msg, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, for your code Count Pop UP to work, let's change all from "" to """"

Second, to be able to notify a Unique PO Number and show it on Pop Up message, you must call the value received from cell G1, or, safer, use evaluate to get the result of this expression.
Your code will probably work now

```
'Dim CountPO As Long
Range("G1").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B22)-ROW(B2),1)),IF(B2:B22<>"""",MATCH(""""&B2:B22,B2:B22&"""",0))),ROW(B2:B22)-  ROW(B2)+1),1))"

MsgBox "We Found " & [g1].Value2 & " PO Open(s)", vbInformation, "PO Found"
```

however, your formula only counts all unique values including less than 500, in addition it is quite long. You can replace it using the shorter formula like the following code:

```
Dim formula_string As String
formula_string = "=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B22>3)*(C2:C22<>"""")/COUNTIF(B2:B22,B2:B22&""""))"

MsgBox "We Found " & Application.Evaluate(formula_string) & " PO Open(s)", vbInformation, "PO Found"
```

Hope it helps!