# Get the last value of a the given header name column in Excel

Tags: excel

i am triying two get the last value of a column given the header name. In the example i need two get 64.

[image]

My attempy is not working

```
INDEX($A$3:D7,MATCH(A3,$A$3:D7;);COUNTA(MATCH($F$3,$A$2:$D$2,)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I must say all credits of this answer go to 2 authors:

> [Last non-empty cell in a
> column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column)
>
> [How to return an entire
> column](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-return-entire-column/)

I just combined these 2 formulas into this:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(B3:D7;0;MATCH(G2;B2:D2;0));MAX((INDEX(B3:D7;0;MATCH(G2;B2:D2;0))<>"")*(ROW(INDEX(B3:D7;0;MATCH(G2;B2:D2;0)))))-2)
```

[image]

Notice at the end I added `-2` and this is critical. It's because your data starts at row 3. If headers were on row 5, and data started at row 6, then it would be `-5` and so on.

And this is how it works in live action. It gets the value of the last **non empty** cell in column.

[image]